# Approximating density from pressure and flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I want to get the density of a fluid going through a pipe.  I can measure the flow and pressure with a flowmeter and the temperature using a thermometer.  With this information, I want to calculate (or approximate) the instantaneous density of the fluid passing through my instruments.

How would I go about doing this?

I'm looking at a liquid (not a gas), mostly incompressible.  Think water with varying amounts of solute (salt, sugar) in it.

Comment: I don't think you can. Different fluids have different compressibilities.

Comment: If your fluid is well described as an [ideal gas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), you could use the equation $\rho = P/(R_{specific}T)$. For air, the [specific gas constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant) $R_{specific} \approx 287\:\:\: J/kg/K$.

Comment: Do you know what fluid it is?

Comment: The density of incompressible liquid does not depend on pressure or flow. If you want to know the salt/sugar content, you could measure conductivity and polarization rotation.

Comment: Without knowing the equation of state in the form $\rho = \rho(p,T)$ you can't make progress.